# "results" vs "is resultant from"

Tags: word-usage, verbs, phrase-usage

So there I am, reading, when I hit this sentence:

> Repeated studies have shown that having excess body fat, type 2 diabetes and weight gain **are resultant from** eating and storing more calories than one burns.

The author could have just said, "weight gain and diabetes **result** from..." That seems more concise and precise.

Here are my questions:

1. Is "is resultant from" a correct phrase, or is it just a way to make "results from" sound more academic?
2. If it is correct, are there contexts in which "is resultant from" is more appropriate than the regular verb, "results"?

Comment: 1. Doubtful, yes. 2. No. (The only situation in which I have seen it used legitimately was as a noun, and in a special context that I sadly I don't remember.)

Comment: If the prepositional phrase "from eating and storing more calories than one burns" is working as a noun, then you can't put the adjective in front of the preposition. It would have to be "are from resultant eating and storing more calories than one burns."  And that isn't what the sentence is supposed to say.

Answer (score 1):

Life is full of things that one *can* do, but probably shouldn't.

The questions recognize a locution that occurs in the wild:

> ***...is resultant from***

"Is "is resultant from" a correct phrase?"

> Yes. *Resultant* is a legitimate adjective, and it can serve as a subject complement (terminology from Warriner) behind the linking verb "is." Although one can *say* it in English, that doesn't mean that people do. An [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=results+from%2C+is+resultant+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresults%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20resultant%20from%3B%2Cc0) comparison shows "is resultant from" is virtually flat-lined, while "results from" has had a happy life for the lasr two centuries.

"...or is it just a way to make "results from" sound more academic?"

> Although this teeters toward personal opinion, I'd say that *verbose* is a better term than *academic.*.

"If it is correct, are there contexts in which "is resultant from" is more appropriate than the regular verb, 'results'?"

> If one is writing in an academic setting, one should consult the style manual of the leading professional journal in the field. Some sciences, for example, have a strong preference for the passive voice, a mode of expression to which other bodies, e.g., the MLA, are allergic. When in Rome, shoot Roman candles. I'm not sure that adept science writers would like this construction, but I won't challenge their right to speak their own lingo.

*As one who writes primarily in the humanities, I wouldn't touch "is resultant from" with a vaulting pole. It is not incorrect, as such, but it's mercifully rare.*

Comment: As one who writes primarily in the sciences, neither would I.

Answer (score -1):

"Resultant" seems questionable to use in that way.  In mathematics and physics, resultant is often used to describe a single outcome, e.g., "C is the resultant of vectors A and B".  The usage in question suggests that type 2 diabetes, weight gain, and excess body fat (three separate items) are outcomes of the "vector" of "eating and storing more calories than one burns."

This usage has the issue that in math and physics use, multiple input vectors combine to produce ONE resultant vector.  Here, the author has used the term "resultant" to describe *multiple* outcomes.  It could also be argued that "eating and storing more calories than one burns" is a single cause, but I will give the author the benefit of the doubt on that part.

I wouldn't call the author's usage technically incorrect; however, it does veer off from the "one outcome vector" sense of the typical math and science usage.  Since the original author apparently intends to sound scientific, precise, and authoritative, using resultant this way comes across as a puffed-up misuse of a math and physics term.  I believe simpler, more ordinary language would have come across as more credible.